# Cant click links asp.net Listview results, its just normal text

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview with some links for example http://www.google.com. that are outputted to a Asp Label. But the link is just plain text, it isnt clickable, does anyone know how to make all links clickable in each listview? Thanks for any help

Edit:note that the Label does not display only a link, the label displays a paragraph of information and in that paragraph, a link may be in there.

Comment: what i think is your problem lies in using labels to show because label do not have clickable interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i think is your problem lies in using labels to show the links because label do not expose clickable interface instead bind your values in

```
<a href='<%#Eval("urlfield")%>'><%#Eval("field")%></a>
```

so that you can click on it and redirect the user, If you wish to get any binded values at server side then use link button and use commanargument and commandname prop's of it.

and yes as our peer tim suggested you can use hyperlink also to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The `Label` control isn't a hyperlink.  I'd suggest using the `HyperLink` control in your ItemTemplate:

[HyperLink Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx)